# How to convert RTCI420Buffer n Webrtc to CVPixelBuffer for iOS ？

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt6yR.jpg)

```
/// Convert RTCVideoFrame to CVPixelBuffer
func getCVPixelBuffer(frame: RTCVideoFrame?) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    var buffer : RTCCVPixelBuffer?
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    
    if let inputBuffer = frame?.buffer {
        if let iBuffer = inputBuffer as? RTCI420Buffer {
            if let cvPixelBuffer = iBuffer.convertToCVPixelBuffer() {
                // Use the cvPixelBuffer as an RTCCVPixelBuffer
                // ...
                pixelBuffer = cvPixelBuffer
                return pixelBuffer
            }
            return pixelBuffer
        }
    }
    
    buffer = frame?.buffer as? RTCCVPixelBuffer
    pixelBuffer = buffer?.pixelBuffer
    return pixelBuffer
}
```

It is a question from [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419635/how-to-add-picture-in-picture-pip-for-webrtc-video-calls-in-ios-swift) but not show about function of `convertToCVPixelBuffer`

So I don't know how convertToCVPixelBuffer works ！

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer now i share it.
You need import <libyuv/libyuv.h>
You can find some libyuv demos from github.

- (CVPixelBufferRef)convertToCVPixelBufferWithI420Buffer:(RTCI420Buffer *)buffer
  {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;

  NSDictionary *pixelBufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSDictionary dictionary],
  (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
  nil];

  CVReturn result = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
  buffer.width,
  buffer.height,
  kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange,
  (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)pixelBufferAttributes,
  &pixelBuffer);

  if (result != kCVReturnSuccess) {
  return NULL;
  }

  result = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

  if (result != kCVReturnSuccess) {
  NSLog(@"convertToCVPixelBufferWithI420Buffer result = %d",result);
  CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
  return NULL;
  }

  uint8 *dstY = (uint8 *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
  int dstStrideY = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
  uint8* dstUV = (uint8*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
  int dstStrideUV = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);

  int ret = I420ToNV12(buffer.dataY,
  buffer.strideY,
  buffer.dataU,
  buffer.strideU,
  buffer.dataV,
  buffer.strideV,
  dstY,
  dstStrideY,
  dstUV,
  dstStrideUV,
  buffer.width,
  buffer.height);

  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
  if (ret) {
  NSLog(@"I420ToNV12 ret = %d",ret);
  CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
  return NULL;
  }

  return pixelBuffer;

}

Comment: format properly

Answer (score 0):

So I up-voted the previous post because it worked (although it needed some fixes).

Here is the updated Objective-C code:

```
+ (CVPixelBufferRef)convertToCVPixelBufferWithI420Buffer:(RTCI420Buffer *)buffer {

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    NSDictionary *pixelBufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSDictionary dictionary], (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, nil];

    CVReturn result = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, buffer.width, buffer.height, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)pixelBufferAttributes, &pixelBuffer);

    if (result != kCVReturnSuccess) {
        return NULL;
    }

    result = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    if (result != kCVReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"convertToCVPixelBufferWithI420Buffer result = %d",result);
        CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
        return NULL;
    }

    void *dstY = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    int32_t dstStrideY = (int32_t)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    void *dstUV = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
    int32_t dstStrideUV = (int32_t)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);

    int ret = I420ToNV12(buffer.dataY, buffer.strideY, buffer.dataU, buffer.strideU, buffer.dataV, buffer.strideV, dstY, dstStrideY, dstUV, dstStrideUV, buffer.width, buffer.height);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    if (ret) {
        NSLog(@"I420ToNV12 ret = %d",ret);
        CFRelease(pixelBuffer); return NULL;
    }

    return pixelBuffer;
}
```

Obviously, get rid of the `NSLog` statements if using it. And I will probably convert it to Swift at some point as well (and I will post that code).

Anyway, TY `lewiswsq2211`